# Trouble with DNS resolution of www subdomain when using Safari browser

Tags: dns, cname, domain-forwarding, deployment

I wrote a simple web application, and I hosted it through cyclic (https://www.cyclic.sh/). After hosting the application, I wanted to configure a custom domain. To do this, I entered the following DNS records in my domain provider's DNS settings:

```
Format:
Host Name
Type
TTL 
Target

Record One:
e39d51f1744fb87d0dd7b5c6d7c54d10.www.tkahomeservicesinc.com 
CNAME   
1 hour  
0c1f92bb7979c9dcbd07208d51bfb0a3.bkngfjypgb.acm-validations.aws.

Record Two:
www.tkahomeservicesinc.com  
CNAME   
1 hour  
cyan-busy-bighorn-sheep.cyclic.app.
```

I also configured domain forward as follows:

```
tkahomeservicesinc.com redirects to https://www.tkahomeservicesinc.com
```

This solution works perfectly fine for every browser EXCEPT Safari. On Safari, if I type in `www.tkahomeservicesinc.com` or `cyan-busy-bighorn-sheep.cyclic.app.` (the CNAME target) into the url bar, I get an error that reads `Safari Can't Connect to the Server`. Interestingly, I can connect to the server on Safari if I type `tkahomeservicesinc.com` (no www prefix), `https://www.tkahomeservicesinc.com`, and `cyan-busy-bighorn-sheep.cyclic.app` (the CNAME target without the final ".").

Again, I've only noticed this problem on Safari. Other browsers seem to have no issue reaching the site using the `www.tkahomeservicesinc.com` domain. I'd really appreciate some guidance here!

Edit: The problem occurs with Microsoft Edge as well.

Comment: And its not because of browser caching? Have you tried more than one device?

Comment: @RohitGupta thanks for the response! I do not believe it is due to caching. I’ve tried multiple devices, and I’ve cleared history, cache, and cookies for each one.

Comment: why would you want to force www anyway?

Comment: I don't know much about Safari.  Maybe it's trying HTTP first.  You can see the requests on Chrome Dev Tools under the Network tab.  Is there such a thing as Safari?

Comment: @Steve I don't want to force www, but if a user types `www.tkahomeservicesinc.com` into the browser, I don't want them to get an error because many users add the www subdomain when they type urls.

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm sure Safari has some sort of developer tools. I'll take a look and see if I can narrow down the reasoning. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `www.tkahomeservicesinc.com` doest not respond on 443 (HTTPS) but only on 80 (HTTP). More and more browsers are prefering HTTPS over HTTP. Your DNS configuration seems fine based on DNSViz.

Comment: On my Windows, Safari is a tad munted.  So many websites do not work (the first 8 of mine do not work with any combination of http/https/www)(.  Whereas Firefox, Chrome and Brave are fine with them.  The test would be to try from an apple device.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The site responded to 443 at the time, but I switched hosting providers on Saturday evening and have not reconfigured SSL since doing so. I plan to do that today and see if the new services provider makes a difference. Thank you!

Comment: I switched over to Heroku for my hosting service, and everything seems to work perfectly now. I literally changed nothing except switching from Cyclic to Heroku and appropriately adjusting the DNS records to reflect that change. Because of this, I believe the issue was on Cyclic's end.